# Scala Async and Await Restrictions

Tags: scala, asynchronous

I have a code block like this:

```
val await1: List[Int] = await(futureMethod(id))

val mapped = await1.map(entry => {
  (pq.id, await(anotherFutureMethod(entry.id)))
})
```

This fails because of "await must not be used under a nested function" How could I get around this? Why should this be a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to guess the signatures of your functions, but an example could look like this:

```
def futureMethod(id: Int): Future[List[Int]] = Future.successful(0 to id toList)
def anotherFutureMethod(id: Int): Future[String] = Future.successful(id.toString)

def finalFuture(id: Int) = async {
  val await1 = await(futureMethod(id))
  val mapped = Future.sequence(await1 map anotherFutureMethod)

  await(mapped)
}
```

Using `Future.sequence` could be a possible, non-blocking solution to avoid using nested `await` calls.

Comment: The problem itself is described at https://github.com/scala/async/issues/32 with descriptions of some ways to solve.

 One of the approaches is to write a layer on top of async to lift-up await via hight-order functions.  I recently implement this in scala-gopher [ https://github.com/rssh/scala-gopher ]  (next version, now your must compile master from sources to use this functionality )

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to chain the future calls, not block for them. Blocking
futures defies the purpose of a future.

```
val future1: Future[List[Int]] = futureMethod(id)

val mapped = future1.map(_.flatMap(anotherFutureMethod)
  .map(entry => {
    (pq.id, entry.id)
  }))
```

Comment: await from async/await doesn't block actually, async is a macro https://github.com/scala/async

Comment: @dk14 oh neat, I didn't know about that library.